# AD and Exchange Migration - 2003 to 2008 R2

Tags: active-directory, exchange, migration, admt

I am working on a project where we need to migrate a 2003 AD domain to a 2008 R2, they also have exchange 2003 in place, and all users account would need to be migrated to exchange 2010.

So, what I know, is that we are going to create a trust between 2003 domain and 2008 R2 domain, after the trust has established I am planning to run the ADMT 3.2 so that I can migrate all users,groups etc, but how about exchange???? I know that I can dump the mailboxes to a pst file and then do the import... but what happened with the user mailbox after the migration??? it will still point to exchange 2003? if so, i will need to brake that in order to create the mail on exchange 2010, or not??? How can I a accomplish this task???

We only have 150 users, and the exchange DB is around 40GB, also any advise on the AD migration would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Exactly this type of work is well documented by Microsoft, just try searching for it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a cross-forest migration of Exchange after doing ADMT. Or use a 3rd-party tool to do the same thing. Or export to PST and import on the new server.

ADMT doesn't do Exchange, and in fact specifically strips out the MSExch attributes on groups and users, so you have to re-apply email addresses on DLs, and then mail-enable them, etc.